# FastAPI - async database query without waiting for response?

Tags: python, sql, fastapi

My goal is to submit a query using SQL alchemy, and not wait for it's response / result.

I need to refresh a materialized postgres view by running a long query e.g.

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW view_name
```

**What is the best practice to submit such async job using FastApi route?**

Using the recommendations in the docs, I have an `async_session` which attempts to `rollback/commit`.

```
async def get_async_session() -> AsyncSession:
    async with ASYNC_SESSION_FACTORY() as session:
        try:
            yield session
            await session.commit()
        except Exception:
            await session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            await session.close()
```

My route:

```
@router.post(
    "/refresh-views",
)
async def endpoint(
    session=Depends(get_async_session),
):
    res = session.execute(
        f"""
        REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW view_name;
        """
    )
    return 200
```

Comment: Have you looked at FastAPI's support for Background Tasks? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/ - however, if you want more fine-grained control (i.e. only a single refresh running at the same time) in your own code, you'll have to add locking yourself.

Comment: This is it. Thanks. Technically, I have sequential refreshes, but I figure I can do them in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fastapi background tasks

```py
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks


async def execute_query(stmt):
    session = await get_async_session()
    await session.execute(stmt)


@router.post(
    "/refresh-views",
)
async def endpoint(
    session=Depends(get_async_session),
    background_tasks: BackgroundTasks

):
    stmt = "REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW view_name;"
    background_tasks.add(execute_query, stmt)
    return 200
```

### Reference:

- https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/